# Updating all rows but one that have same values on certain columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the following schema

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_table 
(
    id_bucket int2 NOT NULL, 
    id_property int2 NOT NULL,
    v1 varchar(320) NOT NULL,
    v2 varchar(320) NULL
);
```

And the following data

```
id_bucket  id_property v1   v2
------------------------------
1          3           OT   A
1          8           RO   C
1          2           OT   C
1          1           RT   D   
1          5           OT   C
1          4           OT   C
```

I would like that all rows that have the same values for v1 and v2 (in this case v1 = OT, v2 = C) be updated with a value for v2 of `NULL` **except for one, regardless**.

I tried grouping by my criterias, but then I lose the details of the rows in question. I know `id_property` will probably be useful, but when using GROUP BY's, I don't have access to that column.

I've been pulling my hair out for a while on this one. Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: "**except for one.**" Which one?

Comment: All we know is you've been pulling your hair out, but we don't know your expected results or your query attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution are [analytic functions aka window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html).

```sql
UPDATE tmp_table
SET v2 = NULL
WHERE (id_bucket,
       id_property) in -- this assumes these columns form a unique key
    (SELECT id_bucket,
            id_property
     FROM
       (SELECT id_bucket,
               id_property,
               row_number() OVER (
                  PARTITION BY v1, v2) rn -- numbers rows with identical v1 and v2
                                                
        FROM tmp_table
       ) x
     WHERE rn > 1 
    ); -- removes the first row with identical v1, v2
```

Results in

| id_bucket | id_property | v1 | v2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | OT | A |
| 1 | 8 | RO | C |
| 1 | 2 | OT | C |
| 1 | 1 | RT | D |
| 1 | 5 | OT | *null* |
| 1 | 4 | OT | *null* |

[See the DB-fiddle for a full example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wyWwpvdE7pRgMsNB6AkmBL/1).

The benefit of a solution based on window functions is that the underlying table gets selected only once, while comparable solutions based on group by in general need to select the table at least a second time. This makes window functions much more efficient.
Of course, that is only really relevant when table get large.

Comment: I knew I'd have to use unicity of rows (which are the rows you assumed) but then by using GROUP BY to have a count of rows that have same v1 and v2, I'd was losing a way of addressing them.

Comment: There are ways to do that, but they are inefficient (see my last update). And with a multipart unique key as you seem to have it gets really bad. Bad as tricky, ugly and slow.